# R cut dates utilizing position, not actual date

Tags: r

I understand that I can cut dates in the following manner:

```
library(tidyverse)
dates <- parse_date(c("2018-02-01", "2018-02-15", "2018-02-20", "2018-03-20"))
cut.dates <- cut(dates, breaks = parse_date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-02-10", "2018-12-31")))
table(cut.dates)
```

But how do I cut dates based on each respective dates' position in the list, not the actual date? I want to replace my third line shown above with something like:

```
cut.dates <- cut(dates, c(0, 2, nrow(dates))
```

`0` would be the initial position to start the cut

`2` would be a cut between the *1st* and *2nd* entry in the list

`nrow(dates)` would be the final cut - the last position in my list

Comment: `split(vec, cut(seq_along(vec), c(0,2,Inf), labels=FALSE))`

Comment: did you mean to put `split(dates, cut(seq_along(dates), c(0,2,Inf), labels=FALSE))`?

Comment: Almost, but the result is `FALSE` when I do the *identical* test in R `identical((cut(dates, breaks = parse_date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-02-10", "2018-12-31")))), (split(dates, cut(seq_along(dates), c(0,2,Inf), labels=FALSE))))`

Comment: The vector is now split on position. What exactly are you expecting in response? Have you tried just the `cut` portion to see what is happening? (It is splitting the indices, not the vector.)

Comment: Whatever answer is submitted has to generate the same output as `cut.dates`. The simplest way to confirm would be issuing the command `identical(cut.dates, your.answer)`. I do like your input and am upvoting it.

Comment: How (from `dates` alone) is the code supposed to know what the levels are supposed to be? Why, for instance, is the level of `dates[1]` `"2018-01-01"` and not `"1997-09-22"` (some other arbitrary date)?

Comment: My actual analysis covers rolling 12 month periods. The cuts are every 3 months, in essence *quarters*. Each time I do the analysis I have to manually change the dates. I'd prefer for the analysis to simply understand that the cuts are between the 3rd and 4th month, 6th and 7th month, 9th and 10th month, and 12th and 1st month. That's why I need everything by position, although the months change the cut position does not.

Comment: That's completely different than a position in the list. It sounds like you need to use the normal `breaks=` method (with actual dates), but based on dates that are programmatically based on the data itself. Try `start <- lubridate::floor_date(dates[1], unit="month") ; breaks <- seq(start, start+365, by="quarter")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have the dates used for cutting dynamically determined from the data instead of manually specifying them.

I'll generate some more dates, since it's hard to test four dates on a quarterly basis when they are all in the same quarter.

```
set.seed(2)
( dates <- sort(Sys.Date() + sample(365, size=20)) )
#  [1] "2018-06-12" "2018-07-03" "2018-07-17" "2018-07-20" "2018-07-24"
#  [6] "2018-08-04" "2018-08-10" "2018-10-07" "2018-10-19" "2018-11-01"
# [11] "2018-11-29" "2018-11-30" "2018-12-12" "2019-01-28" "2019-02-10"
# [16] "2019-03-12" "2019-04-22" "2019-04-23" "2019-05-10" "2019-05-13"
```

Come up with the start and end dates:

```
( start <- lubridate::floor_date(min(dates), unit="quarter") )
# [1] "2018-04-01"
( end <- lubridate::ceiling_date(max(dates), unit="quarter") )
# [1] "2019-07-01"
```

We are interested in quarters:

```
( brks <- seq(start, end, by="quarter") )
# [1] "2018-04-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-10-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-04-01"
# [6] "2019-07-01"
cut(dates, breaks=brks)
#  [1] 2018-04-01 2018-07-01 2018-07-01 2018-07-01 2018-07-01 2018-07-01
#  [7] 2018-07-01 2018-10-01 2018-10-01 2018-10-01 2018-10-01 2018-10-01
# [13] 2018-10-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-04-01 2019-04-01
# [19] 2019-04-01 2019-04-01
# Levels: 2018-04-01 2018-07-01 2018-10-01 2019-01-01 2019-04-01
```

If you don't need to align on calendar quarters -- just grouping data into three months at a time -- then you can instead do:

```
( start_m <- lubridate::floor_date(min(dates), unit="month") )
# [1] "2018-06-01"
( end_m <- lubridate::ceiling_date(max(dates) + 93L, unit="month") )
# [1] "2019-09-01"
( brks_m <- seq(start_m, end_m, by="quarter") )
# [1] "2018-06-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-12-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-06-01"
# [6] "2019-09-01"
```

(The magic `93L` is to ensure we have at least another quarter outside of the current month, only necessary because `ceiling(month)` may not go far enough to capture three months from the previous custom quarter. Generating too many breaks is not a bad thing, the extras will just go unused.)